# jquery form crashing on submit

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am using Xampp and just started learning web dev.
Basically i am trying to learn how to use jquery to submit a form without having to change page, bare in mind i do know it has no validation in and this is for my learning practice.

So myy issue is when i click submit it is causing my webpage to freeze and crash, have I done something wrong with the code i am trying to learn to use?

register.php

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
        <script src="js/submit.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="myForm" method="post">
            Username:    <input name="username" id="username" type="text" /><br />
            Email:   <input name="email" id="email" type="text" /><br />
            Password:<input name="password" id="password" type="password" /><br /> 
            <input type="button" id="submitFormData" onclick="SubmitFormData();" value="Submit" />
        </form>
        ==============================
        <br />
        <div id="results"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

js/submit.js

```
function SubmitFormData() {
    var username = $("#username").val();
    var email = $("#email").val();
    var pass = $("#password").val();
    $.post("submit.php", { 
        username: username, 
        email: email, 
        pass: pass
    }, function(data) {
        $('#results').html(data);
        $('#myForm')[0].reset();
    });
}
```

submit.php

```
<?php
  echo $_POST['username'] ."<br />";
  echo $_POST['email'] ."<br />";
  echo $_POST['pass'] ."<br />";
  echo "==============================<br />";
  echo "All Data Submitted Successfully!";
?>
```

thanks

Comment: Have you errors in the console when inspecting element?

Comment: @djl nope no errors and when i submit the whole page freezes and then after 10-15 secs 'aw snap google chrome has crashed' or whatever it displays.

Comment: I think your `$_POST["name"]` is incorrect. Your javascript says it should be `$_POST["username"]`

Comment: @CoconutsNeedWarmth ahh yes i noticed that sorry i fixed that now on my end i'll edit this one but still getting the crash D:

Comment: have you tried another browser?

Comment: @A.Wolff what do you mean? I'm confused sorry

Comment: Is the `$('#myForm')[0].reset()` working?

Comment: Hi tried the above code in my lampp. But its throwing RangeError, 
Jquery tracker: https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12233

Comment: My bad, you are using input type button, so you don't submit the form. Now i guess your error is server side but following your posted code, i don't see anything wrong there. Check for server side script error or network one

Comment: Did you check network tab of your debugger ? Is the request's response from submit.php proper ?

Comment: Try this and check if there is any error on Ajax path `$.post('submit.php', { username: username, 
        email: email, 
        pass: pass})
    .done( function(msg) { ... } )
    .fail( function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(xhr.responseText);
    });`

Comment: fixed by dinesh thanks for your time and reply guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code is working in jquery-2.2.0.min.js, But in 1.11.1 it is throwing RangeError.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
  <form id="myForm" method="post">
     Username:    <input name="username" id="username" type="text" /><br />
     Email:   <input name="email" id="email" type="text" /><br />
     Password:<input name="password" id="password" type="password" /><br /> 
    <input type="submit" id="submitFormData" value="Submit" />
   </form>
   ==============================
   <br />
   <div id="results">
   </div>
   <script>
        $("#myForm").on('submit', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault(); 
            var name = $("#username").val();
            var email = $("#email").val();
            var pass = $("#password").val(); 
            $.post("submit.php", {
                name: name, 
                email: email, 
                pass: pass
            }, function(data, status) { 
                $('#results').html(data);
                $('#myForm').trigger("reset");
            });
            return false;
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The way question asked

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
  <form id="myForm" method="post">
     Username:    <input name="username" id="username" type="text" /><br />
     Email:   <input name="email" id="email" type="text" /><br />
     Password:<input name="password" id="password" type="password" /><br /> 
    <input type="button" id="submitFormData" onclick="SubmitFormData();" value="Submit" />
   </form>
   ==============================
   <br />
   <div id="results">
   </div>
   <script>
    function SubmitFormData() {
        var username = $("#username").val();
        var email = $("#email").val();
        var pass = $("#password").val();
        $.post("submit.php", { 
            name: username, 
            email: email, 
            pass: pass
        }, function(data) {
            $('#results').html(data);
            $('#myForm').trigger('reset');
        });
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here only change, I have changed the jQuery version.

The above two methods are working. Might be jquery version issue.

Comment: Please check this https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12233. I am also getting same error with 1.11.1, But in 2.x not getting error.

Comment: @DineshPatra that's great thanks alot :) last question if you dont mind ... is this an effective way of submitting a form or not?and i selected answer :)

Comment: @JoshGumpter - Not an effective way because your password would be visible in clear text.

Comment: @JoshGumpter Lance is correct, as you are passing password, according to me it is not a good idea to submit via ajax, Also as it is wrking in 2.x jquery version, and 2.x does not support IE < 9, so take care about that also. Instead of $.post, try with $.ajax, i think it might not cause issue in jquery 1.11

Comment: @JoshGumpter - Try my solution. Moreover, if my solution works, no need to mark it accepted. Just an up-vote would do! :)

Comment: @DineshPatra and Lance i figured yer its not safe to store in database or anything. Good practice is 
$password=md5($password);
 right??

Comment: @JoshGumpter - Do not use `md5` or `sha1` because they are vulnerable now. Use `password-hash`. Go here - http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Comment: @LancePreston thank you for this new encryption method. Before time I was using sha256.  sha256 can be decrypted. password-hash is one way encryption like MD5. But can you please provide an explanation why password-hash, not md5 ? I mean why md5 is less secure, as both are one way encryption. It will be very helpfull.

Comment: On the internet you can find `Rainbow Tables` for `sha1` and `md5`. These `Rainbow Tables` have pre-hassed passwords in `sha1` and `md5`. Hence, if someone gets hold of the `md5` hash, he/she can do a lookup in these `Rainbow Tables` and get the password easily.

Comment: Thank you @LancePreston, for this good explanation. I was unaware of Rainbow Table. It's really helpful for me.

Comment: Good Luck! :) @DineshPatra

Answer (score 2):

Use `var formData = $("#myform").serialize()` instead!

```
$(document).ready(function() {

// process the form
$("#myform").submit(function(event) {

    // get the form data
    // there are many ways to get this data using jQuery (you can use the class or id also)
    var formData = $("#myform").serialize();


    // process the form
        $.ajax({
            type        : 'POST', // define the type of HTTP verb we want to use (POST for our form)
            url         : 'register.php', // the url where we want to POST
            data        : formData, // our data object
            dataType    : 'html', // what type of data do we expect back from the server
            encode      : true
        })
        // using the done promise callback
    .done(function(data) {
            console.log(data);

    });

});

    // stop the form from submitting the normal way and refreshing the page
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Why it will return `empty` or `null`?

Comment: If the `type` of password field in `HTML` is set to `type=password`, it will return `empty` or `null`.

Comment: No this is not the case. I can get value of `$("#password").val()`.

Comment: @Mr.Engineer - Because your password field is marked as `type=text`

Comment: No i know how to make `password` field in HTML. Thanks.

Comment: @Mr.Engineer - Okay. My bad! Good luck.